# about sql insert into date

Tags: mysql, sql-server

here is my table

```
Create table artist_song (
Artist_id int not null,
Song_id int not null,
Artist_song_type varchar(255) not null,
Artist_song_order int not null,
Constraint artist_song_pk primary key (artist_id, song_id),
Constraint artist_song_fk1 foreign key(artist_id) references artist(artist_id),
Constraint artist_song_fk2 foreign key(song_id) references song(song_id)
);
```

and I want to insert into date

```
INSERT INTO artist_song (artist_id, song_id, artist_song_type, artist_song_order) VALUES (2,13,'music',1);
```

but it said that

```
14:19:27    INSERT INTO artist_song (artist_id, song_id, artist_song_type, artist_song_order) VALUES (2,13,'music',1)   Error Code: 1062. 
Duplicate entry '2-13' for key 'PRIMARY'    0.000 sec
```

What should I DO? 
need I change artist_id ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? sql server <> mysql

Comment: Looks like you have a primary key violation to me.

Comment: @Sean Lange, From the error message I can tell that it's an MS SQL Server

Comment: @SQLChao Could you paste here result of some query for this table, like ``SELECT * FROM ARTIST_SONG``? Maybe you are trying to insert duplicated entry.

Comment: does the table artist_song already have a record with artist_id = 2 and song_id=13 ?

Comment: @Kamil from the error message I can tell you that it is NOT sql server. "Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'" is a mysql error. And the message in sql server for 1062 has nothing to do with duplicate primary keys. It is for using TOP N WITH TIES with no order by.

Answer (score 1):

So here you have created Composite key, or composite primary key, refers to cases where more than one column is used to specify the primary key of a table.

So it seems there already exists a record with '2-13' entry in your Database table.Please check your table.

So in you table there must be 'artist_id' with value 2 and 'song_id' with value 13.

So whenever you define a primary key, it is unique throughout your column and since here you have created unique composite key it will be combinaiton of two must be unique throughout your table.